# Application returns "[ClassName] does not exist in namespace" even though it's clearly declared in the same namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I'm using code from here the Windows95-WPF GitHub project, however even if that's the case I *really* can't seem to find a problem here.

I tried changing the namespace, tried verifying the namespace was referenced properly across all files, that `local:` referenced the same namespace, etc etc etc.
There are going to be other errors if anyone tries to compile since it depends on Windows95.dll, but I'm not concerned with other errors, it's this one that's driving me nuts.

As you can see the namespace seems to be referenced everywhere properly... I'm running .net 5 btw

Here's the MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace RadioSim
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the MainWindow.xaml (line 94 is where the error is)

```
<Window x:Class="RadioSim.MainWindow"
        xmlns="*****"
        xmlns:x="*****"
        xmlns:d="*****"
        xmlns:mc="*****"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RadioSim"
        xmlns:windows95="clr-namespace:Windows95;assembly=Windows95"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800"
        Background="#C3C3C3"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Icon="Images/windows.ico">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Margin="20,12,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock Text="Welcome to"
                       FontFamily="Times New Roman"
                       FontSize="28"
                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                       TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased"
                       TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
                       TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Fixed"
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />

            <TextBlock Text="Windows"
                       FontFamily="Arial"
                       FontSize="28"
                       FontWeight="Black"
                       Margin="6,0,0,0"
                       TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased"
                       TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
                       TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Fixed"
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />

            <TextBlock Text="95"
                       x:Name="WindowsVersionTextBlock"
                       FontFamily="Arial"
                       FontSize="28"
                       Margin="2,0,0,0"
                       TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased"
                       TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
                       TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Fixed"
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                       Foreground="White" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Margin="0,48,16,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Button Width="115"
                    Height="23"
                    Margin="0,0,0,7"
                    Content="What's New" />

            <Button Width="115"
                    Height="23"
                    Margin="0,0,0,7"
                    Content="Online Registration"
                    Click="OnlineRegistration_Click" />

            <Button Width="115"
                    Height="23"
                    Margin="0,0,0,7"
                    Content="Next Tip"
                    Click="NextTip_Click" />
        </StackPanel>

        <Button Width="115"
                Height="23"
                Margin="0,0,16,16"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Content="Close"
                Click="CloseButton_Click" />

        <Rectangle Stroke="#828282"
                   Width="115"
                   Height="1"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                   Margin="0,0,16,51" />

        <Rectangle Stroke="#FFFFFF"
                   Width="115"
                   Height="1"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                   Margin="0,0,16,50" />
        
        <local:TipBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      Margin="20,48,0,0"
                      Width="360"
                      Height="160"
                      x:Name="MainTipBox">
            <local:TipBox.TipText>
                You can change this text by placing a file named 'tips.txt' near the program executable. It's a JSON list.
            </local:TipBox.TipText>
        </local:TipBox>

        <CheckBox Content="Show this Welcome Screen next time you start Windows"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Margin="20,0,0,19"
                  IsChecked="True"
                  IsEnabled="False"
                  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here's the TipBox .xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="RadioSim.TipBox"
             xmlns="*****"
             xmlns:x="*****"
             xmlns:mc="*****" 
             xmlns:d="*****" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RadioSim"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="152" d:DesignWidth="328"
             Name="Control">
    <Grid Background="#FFFFFF">
        <Border Background="Transparent"
                BorderThickness="1,1,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                BorderBrush="#828282" />
        
        <Border Background="Transparent"
                BorderThickness="0,0,1,1"
                Margin="0,1,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                BorderBrush="White" />
        <Grid Background="#20FFFF00" Margin="1">
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Margin="28,20,0,0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Image Source="Images/TipIcon.png"
                   Width="23"
                   Height="32"
                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" />

                    <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial"
                           FontWeight="Bold"
                           FontSize="12"
                           Text="Did you know..."
                           Margin="18,6,0,0"
                           TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased"
                           TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" />
                </StackPanel>
                
                <TextBlock x:Name="TooltipText"
                           Margin="69,0,40,0"
                           FontFamily="Arial"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           xml:space="preserve"
                           Text="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=TipText}"
                           TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased"
                           TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" />
            </StackPanel>

            
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Lastly, this is the TipBox.xaml.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace RadioSim
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TipBox.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TipBox : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TipTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TipText", typeof(string), typeof(TipBox), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

        public string TipText
        {
            get { return (string) GetValue(TipTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TipTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public TipBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

OBS: I removed the links in the XAMLs because the Spam filter was being annoying

Comment: Where exactly doe you get this error?

Comment: Line 94 of the MainWindow.xaml where you have ``<local:TipBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"(etc)``

Comment: It would be better to [edit] your question and add this information directly there.

Comment: Also note, that .NET5 is out of support since almost two years.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a Problem that I get often as well.
In my case it usually works to rebuild the Project/Solution. So in your IDE just go up to Build and then click rebuild

Comment: If this doesn't help: there is a VS extension called "Clean Bin and Obj" which really cleans bin and obj and not only half of them as VS' integrated "Clean" or "Rebuild" do.

Comment: I'll try the extension, thank you very much. As Oliver mentioned, the usual Clean and Rebuild did no good.

Comment: Ah shame well sorry i couldnt be of help